# Connect React client to PHP server with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

What are the steps need to follow to connect a react client to a PHP backend with MySQL database?

Comment: Your client shouldn't have to care at all what you've built the server in, it just makes requests and gets responses.

Comment: Thanks for the information..Is there any reference I can use that you have? If so be kind to attach here..

Comment: We don't do recommendations for tutorials here, sorry. You should be able to search online successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a webservice to provide data for react app. it won't really mater what really in backend to connect. You can utilise the webservice through axios no matter what backend is.

Comment: Thanks for the information..Is there any reference I can use that you have? If so be kind to attach here..

Comment: Pls find the article https://www.techiediaries.com/php-react-rest-api-crud-tutorial/